# Git extension in Visual Studio 2019 Community not tracking multiple project changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 Community solution with two projects. One is a Blazor Server side project and the other is an xUnit Test project. Each project has its own local and remote Git repo. When I have both projects visible in the IDE and I make changes in Blazor project, they are tracked by Git and show in the Team Explorer view as modified files. When I make changes to class files in the xUnit project, they are not shown as modified files by Git in Visual Studio. When I change into the xUnit project folder in a CLI, and invoke a git status, I see the updated files listed. When I open the xUnit project in its own solution separately in Visual Studio, the changes are visible by the Git extension.

Why is the Git extension in Visual Studio 2019 only tracking changes in the Blazor project and not in the xUnit project when both projects are present in the IDE?

Comment: If I understand well, you have 2 git repositories and you ask why VS2019 can't manage 2 repositories at the same time? The answer is in the question. Because VS could handle only one repository.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe. I ran across older posts articulating the fact that in older versions of VS, only one repo is tracked. Just wanted to make sure that it was the case with VS 2019 and that I was not overlooking anything.

Comment: I don't know one editor/IDE that handle multiple repository from scratch. If you have these dependencies, that shows that you should put everything inside one repo (see monorepo)

Comment: @Philippe Visual Studio Code manages multiple repositories without breaking a sweat.